# Boxplot for several variables with different Y scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have 4 variables (A, B, C, D) with similar pattern on 3 Locations. I would like to plot a box plot (variables as dots on Y-axis, locations as X). But the variables have values of different orders of magnitude. Is there a way of scaling the Y-axis and have all variables plotted on the boxplots? Maybe differenced by colouring.

```
Location = c("Washington","Washington","Washington","Washington","Washington","Washington", "Maine","Maine","Maine","Maine","Maine", "Florida","Florida","Florida","Florida","Florida","Florida")
A = c(0.000693156,  0.000677354,    0.000727863,    0.000650822,    0.000908343,    0.001126689,    0.001316292,    0.000975274,    0.00109082, 0.001057585,    0.000927826,    0.000552769,    0.000532546,    0.000559781,    0.000771569,    0.000563436,    0.000551136)
B = c(0.001915388,  0.001936627,    0.001476521,    0.001573681,    0.002584282,    0.00738909, 0.008089839,    0.006616564,    0.00495211, 0.004515925,    0.003791596,    0.000653847,    0.000350701,    0.000559781,    0.001920087,    0.000738206,    0.001077627)
C = c(0.000138966,  0.000104745,    0.000145573,    0.000103305,    5.08255E-05,    0.000361988,    0.000264876,    0.000454172,    0.000277471,    0.000117919,    8.9214E-05, 0.000173727,    0.000108241,    8.54628E-05,    2.35593E-05,    3.1302E-05, 1.12019E-05)
D = c(0.000108829,  0.000135005,    0.000120617,    9.29746E-05,    0.000105561,    9.27596E-05,    0.000121317,    0.000131471,    0.000152503,    0.000128974,    0.000196271,    0.000142141,    0.000147208,    0.00013674, 0.000147246,    0.000185204,    0.000103058)

df = data.frame(Location, A, B, C, D)
```

And this is what I have tried for two variables as individual graphs

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Location, y=A)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
a + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1, fill="red")

b <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Location, y=B)) + 
      geom_boxplot()
b + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1, fill="blue")
```

- Can I merge all 4 variables in 1 graph with a scaled Y-axis?
- Can I add a legend only showing "A" and "D"?

[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reshape your data to "long" format, faceting is one option. Note that you must set `scales = 'free'` in `facet_wrap()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(A:D, names_to = 'variable', values_to = 'value')

g <- ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Location, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~variable, scales = 'free')
print(g)
```

[image]

If you wanted to get everything on one plot, you'd have to rescale the data per group. Here I've normalized each data point to between 0 and 1, relative to its original scale.

```
df.long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(A:D, names_to = 'variable', values_to = 'value') %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(value_norm = value - min(value), 
         value_norm = value_norm / max(value_norm)
  )

g.norm <- ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Location, y = value_norm, fill = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot()
print(g.norm)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of plotting them all in one plot and the Y- axis being at scaled value? Something like: mutate(scaled_val = scale(value)) ?

Comment: See edit. You'll have to manually scale your data but the tidyverse makes that pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Using `scale_y_log10`. Not the most beautiful plot, but ...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Location) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Location, y=value, color = name)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = name), color = "black", binaxis='y', dotsize=.5) +
  scale_y_log10()
#> `stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>